# jQuery fadeIn on array elements one at at time

Tags: jquery

I have an array

```
var myarray = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ];
```

And I want each element to be placed between

```
<H1> </H1>
```

and then make it fade in one at a time.  A fades in first, and then B, C, D, E start fading in one at a time.  At the moment everything appears all at once.

jsfiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/c2hsmb2h/2/

What am I missing here?   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/c2hsmb2h/3/

start items as hidden

```
list = list + "<H1 class='page1class' style='display:none;'>"+entry+"</H1>";
```

and add them to div first and after that fade them in. You didn't start them as hidden and you added the list to the div after fading them in so they were all already visible when added to the div.

Comment: EXCELLENT!! EXCELLENT!!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c2hsmb2h/4/

You can write a basic function that accepts a delay parameter and have the loop increment that value... well, just look at the code...

```
var myarray = [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

function addElement(elem, delay)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('<h1>').css('opacity', 0).text(elem).appendTo($("#mydiv")).animate({opacity:1}, 500);
    }, delay);
}

$("#thisbutton").click( function(){
    $("#mydiv").empty();
    $.each(myarray, function(i,v){
        addElement(myarray[i], i * 200);
    });
});
```

PS - why do you want them all in h1 tags within the same parent? Want to violate html standards or something?

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I was not aware that it violates HTML standards.  Is there something wrong with putting them all in H1 tags?  You can tell me.  I am still a rookie.

Comment: And you can tell me what the better way is, if putting them all in H1 tags is not recommended.

Comment: Basic idea is h1 is single use within a primary element, like a section or aside, etc. Pretty much all you need to do to avoid this expectation is to put them in any other tag. h2 is fine, for example.